# How do I reference a JSP in a Servlet

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, servlets, eclipse-wtp

I have a jsp file that contains all the html and javascript that I want for my website.

Is it possible for me to **create a servlet and then have the servlet reference the jsp file** (instead of putting all the html into the servlet)?

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  //initiate jsp file
}
```

Comment: What's the servlet doing that you wouldn't have the JSP do?

Comment: Nothing. The servlet would just be a wrapper for the JSP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is as below :

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
                 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/thankYou.jsp");
                 dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

or else you can set `welcome-file` also as jsp page in your `web.xml` if you dont need to instantiate Servlet first.

Comment: Have a great start !! Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in such a simple way

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(response
                                    .encodeURL("/file.jsp"));
                    rd.forward(request, response);
```

in response.encodeURL() you can pass the path to the jsp file OR simply map the jsp file in web.xml and put the mapped link to the jsp directly.